# Setting single stylesheet property in Qt

Tags: css, qt

I'm trying to create vertical lines in a QTreeView; rather than painting over lines as suggested by some answers I am using a stylesheet to modify the right border of the cells in the treeview like so:

```
ui->tripsTreeView->setStyleSheet ("QTreeView::item:!last { border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray ;}");
```

Unfortunately this resets all other stylesheet properties on the treeview, making it unusable (white on white text, the expand triangle gets a blue background, custom background colours disappear, etc).

Questions:

- Has someone managed to set a stylesheet for a single property in Qt?
- Or found a way to extract the current *applied* stylesheet? I would then do a search-and-replace to add/set the proper border. Unfortunately `ui->tripsTreeView->styleSheet()` returns only an empty string (meaning it uses the deault stylesheet, but what the heck *is* the default stylesheet?)

Answer (score 0):

When no stylesheet is set Qt uses a style which matches the style of the OS. When you try to change the stylesheet of even a single property the whole stylesheet of the control is replaced with a default one. I am not sure if the default stylesheet can be extracted. Probably a custom delegate with `paint()` function reimplemented can do the trick.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I find it rather inelegant. I'm used to CSS in browsers which work as expected....

Comment: @JvO There's no way to make stylesheets interoperate with native styles, because native styles aren't really easily modifiable. In Qt you can either use an existing style, or you have to set up a *complete* stylesheet for a widget, there's no in-between. As soon as you apply stylesheets, there's no way for them to affect the platform style, so the platform style has to go away.